Weird position update when component has rotate effect
I'm facing this issue when my component has a rotate effect to 90 degree then my onDragUpdate callback is not working correctly anymore.
This is my implementation of onDragUpdate callback
  void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
    super.onDragUpdate(event);
    position += event.localDelta;
  }

How to update position as same as component has no rotate effect?
Anyone who has a solution for this case please let me know.
Thank you very much!

seems like you have to "rotate" by 90 degrees your event.localDelta - for 90 degrees its simple: you swap event.localDelta.dx with event.localDelta.dy (and negating one of them), for other angle you need some basic math

@pskink it's seem a good solution. lemme try it. Thank you very much!

your welcome, btw if you dont like those 2 math lines with sin and cos you can do the same in one line using Offset.fromDirection constructor
